# changing $r=1+2r\cos \theta$ to its cartesian equivalent

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

My textbook says the polar equation, $r=1+2r\cos \theta$, its cartesian equivalent is $y^2-3x^2-4x-1=0.$ I understand that I get this if I square $r$; $r^2=x^2+y^2=(1+2x)^2.$ But don't I need to square root this back or something?? I thought the answer is supposed to be $ \sqrt{y^2-3x-4x-1}=0  $... I'm confused..

Comment: The solutions of the two are the same! ($a=0$ if and only if $\sqrt{a}=0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right that the polar equation $r = (1+2r \cos \theta)$
and the cartesian equation $y^2 - 3x^2 - 4x -1 = 0$ are not *equivalent*.
The solutions of the first one are a *subset* of the solutions of the second.

$y^2 - 3x^2 - 4x -1 = 0$ is equivalent to
$r^2=(1+2r \cos \theta)^2$ and that is equivalent to

$$
   r = (1+2r \cos \theta) \quad\textbf{ or }\quad r = -(1+2r \cos \theta) \quad . 
$$

So your polar equation $r = (1+2r \cos \theta)$ describes one branch of the hyperbola 
 $y^2 - 3x^2 - 4x -1 = 0$ and $r = -(1+2r \cos \theta) $ is the other branch.

Here is an image from [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427ehno1hl71op):

[image]

*Addendum:* I did assume that $r$ must be positive (see below comments), and it
is easy to see that then $x \ge -1/3$ for the first equation and $x \le -1$ for
the second, so each polar equation produces one branch of the hyperbola.

Without this restriction, either equation produces the entire hyperbola,
because the transformation $r \to -r, \theta \to \theta + \pi$ transforms
one equation into the other.

In other words: If $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta $ is a solution of
the cartesian equation  $y^2 - 3x^2 - 4x -1 = 0$ then either
$(r, \theta)$ or $(-r, \theta + \pi)$ is a solution of the polar equation
$r = 1 + 2r \cos \theta$.

Comment: Interestingly, you get _both_ branches of the hyperbola from $r=1+2r\cos\theta.$ You also get both branches from $r=-(1+2r\cos\theta).$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eal8gutsn8h agrees: the polar plot produces both branches.

Comment: @DavidK: The transformation $r \to -r, \theta \to \theta + \pi$ transforms one equation into the other. So perhaps the Wolfram Alpha plot allows negative values for $r$ ?

Comment: I'm sure it allows negative $r$. Why shouldn't it?

Comment: @DavidK: The question (as I understand it) what about polar coordinates. Doesn't that imply $r >= 0$?

Comment: No, I don't think it does.

Comment: @DavidK: Thanks for the feedback. I have updated the answer, I hope that it is correct now.

Comment: It looks good to me now. What you say is quite true: positive values of $r$ are plotted on only on one branch of the hyperbola, and you get the other branch only when you consider negative values. It's an interesting observation, actually, and evidently helps the understanding of this problem.

Answer (score 2):

From $r=1+2r\cos\theta$, we get
$$r(1-2\cos\theta)=1$$
or
$$r(1-2\frac xr)=1$$
$$r-2x=1$$
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=2x+1$$
and finally square to get
$$x^2+y^2=4x^2+4x+1$$